# MySql database optimization on inner join

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, query-optimization, inner-join

I am facing problem while running the below query. It takes longer time for short month duration and time out for longer duration.

```
SELECT DISTINCT rcs.ID,
                rcs.UniqueID,
                rcs.ReferanceNo,
                rcs.OrderDateActual,
                rcs.DelivaredToCus,
                rcs.PacketNumber,
                rcs.PackingCharge,
                rcs.TransportCharge,
                rcs.OtherAdjustment,
                SUM(rcsd.TotalPrice) AS TotalPrice
FROM regular_challan_sales rcs
LEFT JOIN regular_challan_sales_details rcsd ON rcsd.UniqueID = rcs.UniqueID
WHERE rcs.OrderDateActual >= '2013-12-01'
  AND rcs.OrderDateActual <= '2014-05-01'
GROUP BY rcs.UniqueID
ORDER BY rcs.OrderDateActual ASC
```

[image: Here is the table description.]

I need a quick solution please.

Comment: Perhaps start by adding indexes on `rcsd.UniqueID` and `rcs.OrderDateActual`... seems like a bit of a no-brainer that some indexes would help improve the query performance

Comment: Thanks @Mark Barker. Is there any other way. I will try indexes but I need more optimization as my data will be fat day by day...

Comment: Appropriate indexes should always be your main tool for optimisation; a well indexed database will perform well even with billions of records.... and this query is simple enough that it shouldn't need any further optimisation than simple indexing until you do reach billions of records

Comment: As Mark says: indexes are the key. On an RDBMS, indexes are the primary way to optimize, not tweaking Queries in some way. 
Anyhow: what indexes do you have right now, on these two tables?

Comment: well I already fixed the issue. I create index for UniqueID in each table and join the table on UniqueID. That's solved my problem.  I have a little question, how many indexes i can declare in a table?